# How do I get the Create 2 to communicate with a laptop via the serial to USB cable?

Tags: irobot-create, serial, usb

My computer will not recognize the Serial to USB cable.  I have tried it on a Mac and an HP.

Is there a driver that I need to install?  If it is supposed to install automatically, it is not.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a FTDI device, download the latest driver from http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm

I assume its the original USB to Serial cable from iRobot you're using.